# Setting report to current date

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

I have a report where it shows meetings and their requirements.  However i just want the report to show ONLY today's stuff--not the entire week's worth.
I tried setting my group header (i'm grouping by day) to currentdate but yet it still shows me the entire week.  I then have to go to the grouping tree and select today's date.  Is there any way to run my report and have it ONLY show today's stuff and nothing else???

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the select expert to limit the results to today's date. *printdate* is a special Crystal Formula keyword.

```
{table.date_field} = printdate
```

Or, if you're working with a datetime db field you can strip the time with *CDate*

```
CDate({table.date_field}) = printdate
```

Comment: +1 I'd actually probably use CurrentDate or CurrentDateTime, but the idea is the same.

Comment: or you could even go old school and use `today`

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to change your query so that it's only getting one day's worth of data; that is, assuming your data contains a date field. To take it a step further, you could add date parameters to the query itself and leave the group headers as is. That way, you can have one day of data, or data from a specific date range.

If you have no influence (or desire) to change the way data comes into Crystal Reports, you could also add a formula via the Section Expert to suppress the group or detail section unless the date is the current date.

Comment: +1 if you have the ability to limit the data before it comes into the report then I'd do it there first. Otherwise I'd use dotjoe's response to narrow down the criteria that way before it comes into the report. Last resort would be to use the section expert, but sometimes you have to do it that way.